# Approximation using Laurent polynomial

Tags: laurent-series, approximation-theory

I would like to obtain an approximation of a function $1/(a x + b y)$ around $x=1$ in terms of a Laurent polynomial. I do not need the complete series; in fact perhaps the 1st order terms in $x$ and $x^{-1}$ may be sufficient for my purposes, leading to something of the form $\alpha_{-1} x^{-1} + \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 x$. However a Taylor expansion is not what I need. What is the correct way of obtaining such an expansion?

The next step is to expand in $y$ around 1 as well, obtaining something of the form $\alpha_{-1} x^{-1} + \beta_{-1} y^{-1} + \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 x + \beta_1 y$. Is this reasonable?

Comment: The Laurent series is not relevant in the case where there are no poles in the neighborhood where the approximation is needed. Nevertheless, a finite Laurent polynomial might still give a more useful approximation than a truncated Taylor series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding around $x=1$ and $y=1$ seem to be the wrong approaches to take here. The standard approach is to factor the larger (in magnitude) of $ax$ and $by$ out from the denominator, and use the geometric series summation formula in reverse (equivalently, the binomial expansion formula). So:
$$\begin{align} \frac{1}{ax + by} & = \frac{1}{ax} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(-\frac{by}{ax}\right)^n \ \forall\, |ax| > |by|,\ \mathrm{and} \\
& = \frac{1}{by} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(-\frac{ay}{by}\right)^n \ \forall\, |ax| < |by| \end{align}.$$
If you want to expand about a different point, just shift your variables and apply the same formulae. For example:
$$\begin{align} x' &= x - 1,\ \mathrm{and} \\
y' & = y + \frac{a}{b}. \end{align}$$

To more literally apply repeated expansions, as requested in the original post, you'll apply a binomial expansion to each term in one of the above formulae after applying another shift/change of variables. The formula for more general binomial expansions is:
$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{(ax + b)^n} &= \frac{1}{(ax)^n} \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(-n+1)}{m! \Gamma(-n-m+1)} \left(\frac{b}{ax}\right)^m\ \forall\, |ax| > |b|,\ \mathrm{and} \\
& = \frac{1}{b^n} \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(-n+1)}{m! \Gamma(-n-m+1)} \left(\frac{ax}{b}\right)^m\ \forall\, |ax| < |b|. \end{align}$$

Comment: Interesting. I am not yet sure this will solve my particular problem but it's a good explanation of a neat trick.

Comment: Added a term for performing a more general binomial expansion. With variable shifts, the formulae here are sufficient to do exactly what you want.

Comment: @SeanLake Can you show link to this "standard way"?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking for, @YuriNegometyanov. It's a standard trick from calculus where an unknown series is produced by composition. For example, the expansion for a Gaussian function is produced much faster by plugging $-x^2/2$ into the known series for $\operatorname{e}^x$ than grinding through the derivatives and looking for a pattern.

Comment: This may not be exactly what I wanted but it's a good answer that can be useful somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't meet the Laurent polynomials of two variables yet, but it can be used the next considerations.

It is possible to build "the standard" Laurent polynomial only for complex analytic function of **one** variable $z=x+iy$. That gives
$$F(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y),$$
so $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ must satisfy to [Cauchy–Riemann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations) equations
$$\dfrac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}=\dfrac{\partial{v}}{\partial{y}},\quad \dfrac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}}=-\dfrac{\partial{v}}{\partial{x}}.$$
Assuming
$$u(x,y) = \mathcal RF(x+iy)=\dfrac1{ax+by},$$
we have 
$$\dfrac{\partial{v}}{\partial{y}} = -\dfrac{a}{(ax+by)^2},\quad \dfrac{\partial{v}}{\partial{x}} = \dfrac{b}{(ax+by)^2},\quad a=b=0.$$
That means that **there are not** Laurent polynomials for $f(x,y).$
Moreover, it can not be represented as real (or imaginary) part of this series.

At the same time, for the complex function
$$F(z)=1/z$$
$$F(x+iy)=\dfrac{x}{x^2+y^2}-i\dfrac{y}{x^2+y^2},$$
so the function
$$u(x,y)=\dfrac{x}{x^2+y^2}$$
can be presented as the real part of Laurent polynomial.

Within the real analysis, Taylor series of two variables in form
$$f(x,y)=f(x_0,y_0) + f'_x\biggr|_{x=x_0,y=y_0}(x-x_0) + f'_y\biggr|_{x=x_0,y=y_0}(x-x_0)(y-y_0)$$
$$+ \dfrac12f''_{xx}\biggr|_{x=x_0,y=y_0}(x-x_0)^2 + f''_{xy}\biggr|_{x=x_0,y=y_0}(x-x_0)(y-y_0) + \dfrac12f''_{yy}\biggr|_{x=x_0,y=y_0}(y-y_0)^2$$
$$+ \dfrac16f'''_{xxx}\biggr|_{x=x_0,y=y_0}(x-x_0)^3 + \dfrac12f'''_{xxy}\biggr|_{x=x_0,y=y_0}(x-x_0)^2(y-y_0) + \dfrac12f'''_{xyy}\biggr|_{x=x_0,y=y_0}(x-x_0)(y-y_0)^2+ \dfrac16f'''_{yyy}\biggr|_{x=x_0,y=y_0}(y-y_0)^3+\dots.$$
It's easy to see that Taylor series of $n$th order use the full set of partial derivatives to $n$th order.

To obtain the series in negative powers of $(x-x_0)$ and $(y-y_0),$ we can present $f(x,y)$ as $g\left(\dfrac1{x-x_0},\dfrac1{y-y_0}\right),$ where
$$g(r,s) = \dfrac{rs}{as+br+ax_0+by_0},$$ 
and use the above Taylor series in form of Maclaurin series.
It is easy to see that
$$g(0,0)=g'_r(0,0)=g'_s(0,0)=g''_{rr}(0,0)=g''_{ss}(0,0)=g''''_{rrr}(0,0)=g'''_{sss}(0,0).$$
Calculating the [second](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%5E2%2Fdrds%20%7Br%20s%7D%2F%7Ba%20s%2Bb%20r%2Ba%20x_0%2Bb%20y_0%7D)
$$g''_{rs}\biggr|_{r=0,s=0} = \dfrac1{ax_0+by_0}$$
and the [third](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdr%20d%5E2%2Fdrds%20%7Br%20s%7D%2F%7Ba%20s%2Bb%20r%2Ba%20x_0%2Bb%20y_0%7D)
$$g'''_{rrs}\biggr|_{r=0,s=0} = -\dfrac{2b_0^2y_0}{(ax_0+by_0)^2}, \quad g'''_{rrs}\biggr|_{r=0,s=0} = -\dfrac{2a_0^2x_0}{(ax_0+by_0)^2}$$
derivatives, we can get "the Laurent" polynomial in form
$$\dfrac1{ax+by} = \dfrac1{(ax_0+by_0)^2(x-x_0)(y-y_0)}\left(ax_0+by_0 -\dfrac{2b_0^2y_0}{x-x_0}- \dfrac{2a_0^2x_0}{y-y_0}+\dots\right)$$

To choice the reqired form of series, it follows to consider the actual area. Maybe, the Maclaurin series on $((x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2-r^2)$ or similar can satisfy to requirements.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by "there are no Laurent polynomials for $f(x,y)$.

Comment: @Pait Laurent series depends of one complex variable. That gives the possibility to use geometric progression for the ring $a<|z|<b$

Comment: I understand. But a Laurent polynomial is a polynomial with terms on powers of $x^{-1}$ as well as powers of $x$. One may use a Laurent polynomial to approximate a given function, there is no question about its existence.

Comment: @Pait It is a polynomial of one variable, real or complex. $f(x,y)$ can not be presented in that form, so considered approximation should have another name.

Comment: Well, the function $\alpha_{-1} x^{-1} + \beta_{-1} y^{-1} + \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 x + \beta_1 y$ is perfectly well defined provided $x$ and $y$ are not zero, whether real or complex.

Comment: @Pait I see that f(x,y) = f(x)+ f(y), i.e. sum of 1D series.

Comment: No, whats not $f(x,y)$, merely a Laurent polynomial approximation. More terms could be added, such is terms on $xy$ and $x^{-1} y^{-1}$.

Comment: @Pait The advantage of the classic series is their relation to derivatives, which allows to combine the ease of obtaining and transparent behavior. But also other considerations exist.